# How do I use SNAP protocol, correctly?

Tags: c, avr

[I've reviewed the documentation](http://www.hth.com/filelibrary/pdffiles/snap.pdf)

I'm still a little lost when it comes to applying the functions. Each of the redundancy check methods take in an unsigned char and return an unsigned char.

Shouldn't there be some sort of boolean return somewhere confirming that the data is accurate?

I've been trying to debug `unsigned char* tempData = "snap"` to the terminal, writing it directly to the register, according to the doc it should return `h17`:

```
  UDR0 = crc8(tempData,sizeof(tempData));
```

The terminal outputs '?' - as if it cannot be read.

Comment: Whereabouts are these functions you are using?

Comment: This was the only AVR-GCC example implementation of the protocol: http://www.hth.com/filelibrary/snap/usrcode/GCC01.ZIP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `crc8` function calculates the Cyclic Redundancy Check (8-bit) value for the data you provide. It is then up to you to compare that calculated value with the CRC you have received.

The `?` you are seeing in the serial terminal is an *unprintable* character. It is representing an 8-bit value that doesn't lie within the 32-127 range of normal ASCII characters, or 32-255 of the extended ASCII character set.

Comment: Okay! Is this appropriate moving forward?
1) On the transferring node store the value crc8() returns and call it the 'checksum' , then send it as part of the payload.
2) On the receiving node call crc8() on incoming tempData and compare it to checksum?

Comment: I'm sort of concerned that even if this works my implementation is to simple and I'm missing something. I might try another protocol that has stronger avr examples

Comment: The SNAP specification seems very wooly. I'd try something more rigidly defined with proper libraries.  Depending on what you want to achieve my [ICSC](https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/ICSC) library might work well for you.

Comment: My needs are pretty straight forward, I just need to validate incoming packets. Your library looks solid but I'm not running off Arduino. I think it would be challenging to port.